# Вводить слова в строку пока не встретится слово stop

Tags: c, строки, ввод

Подскажите функцию.А то в сin.getline() только символы.Строка С (не string)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *str = new char;
    while(cin >> str){
        if(!strcmp(str, "stop"))
            break;
        cout << str;
    }
}
```

Comment: но это будет работать, только если каждое "сообщение" писать через Enter, можно сделать чтобы сразу в одну строку писало и проверяло, если автору нужно будет то напишу

Comment: Откуда неймспейсы в [tag:c]? Откуда оператор `new`?

Comment: Автор пишет, что работает с cin.getline(), но результат не тот, не следует ли из этого, что он работает в c++...( в C нету cin.getline())

Comment: Вы хотели [`for (string s; (cin >> s) && s != "stop"; ) cout << s << '\n';`](https://ideone.com/iW01yx) написать?